# Result of the summary of the proportional hazard model with frailty in R

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, frailty

I am trying to fit coxph a model with frailty with syntax below:

```
> kidneyExt.cox <- coxph(Surv(time,inf) ~ age+sex+frailty(patient)+strata(type), data=kidneyExt)
> kidneyExt.cox
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, inf) ~ age + sex + frailty(patient) + 
    strata(type), data = kidneyExt)

                 coef     se(coef) se2   Chisq DF p      
age               0.00743 0.012    0.012  0.38 1  5.4e-01
sex              -1.48647 0.371    0.371 16.01 1  6.3e-05
frailty(patient)                          0.00 0  9.3e-01

Iterations: 6 outer, 37 Newton-Raphson
     Variance of random effect= 5e-07   I-likelihood = -112 
Degrees of freedom for terms= 1 1 0 
Likelihood ratio test=15  on 2 df, p=0.000553  n= 76
```

And I am curious about last line about Likelihood ratio test.
Is it a result for a likelihood ratio test? And it's p-value is 0.000553?
I am asking because when I type syntax like this below I got something different from summary.

```
> kidneyExt.cox$loglik
[1] -119.4828 -111.9835
```

Is that test in a summary has it's name if it's not likelihood ratio test?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `kidneyExt.cox$loglik` returns the LLs of a particular model (here `kidneyExt.cox`). The LRT mentioned in the last line tests against a model without any predictors. You should be able to test a model without any predictors against your actual model via `anova(nullmodel, kidneyExt.cox)`.

Comment: what does LLs mean?

Comment: @marcin-kosinksi Sorry, for being sloppy... LL = Log-Likelihood, LLs = Log-Likelihood_s_

Comment: You Just meant plural form :p? Thanks for answer, it was helpfull.